# Sphere - Sphere Intersection : Distance Vector

Tags: math

Is there a way to find out the distance of intersection between 2 spheres ? I understand when two spheres intersect the circle of intersection is formed . But what i'm trying to figure ouut is by how much i will need to push circle 1 outside so that they dont intersect and are at a point where they are just touching each other . The only data i have are the centres of the spheres and their respective radii.

Thanks

Comment: Try http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Define two spheres with centres at position vectors **a** and **b** (i.e. **a** = a<sub>x</sub>**i** + a<sub>y</sub>**j** + a<sub>z</sub>**k**).

Define a vector **c** from centre of sphere A to centre of sphere B:

**c** = **b** - **a**

Its length is |**c**| = |**b** - **a**|

       
= sqrt( [b<sub>x</sub> - a<sub>x</sub>]<sup>2</sup> + [b<sub>y</sub> - a<sub>y</sub>]<sup>2</sup> + [b<sub>z</sub> - a<sub>z</sub>]<sup>2</sup> )

As Mahesh stated, the distance between the two spheres is:

|**d**| = |**c**| - r<sub>A</sub> - r<sub>B</sub>

So the vector **d** from the furthest point of sphere A to the furthest point of B will be either pointing along **c** (when the spheres are not yet intersecting) or in the opposite direction (when the sphere are intersecting).

To move one sphere so they don't intersect, you need to move it by **d**. Since this is along **c**, we can just multiply **c** by a factor to get the components of **d**:

f = ( |**d**| / |**c**| )
**d** = f * **c**

For example, in the x direction:

d<sub>x</sub> = f * c<sub>x</sub>

So I would say try this:

- Compute the components of the displacement **c** from the position vectors of A and B.
- Compute the length of **c** from its components
- Compute the length of **d** from the length of c and the radii
- Compute the factor f between **c** and **d**
- Compute the components of **d** by scaling the components of **c** by the factor f.

You can test whether the spheres intersect by testing the sign on f: if it is negative then the spheres intersect. You can then either move A or B by **d**, or both by some portion of **d** so that they no longer intersect.

Answer (score 1):

`( radius1 + radius2 ) - ( Current distance between the two centers )` is the amount of distance to be moved by either of a sphere to exactly touch each other. ( Assuming spheres are currently intersecting )

Comment: Assuming  three dimensional space , so ( radius1 + radius 2 ) - ( Current distance between the two centers ) would be the distance the object has to move in all of x y and z ??

Comment: @Krishnan- No, it's the magnitude of the distance.  If you want to get the vectors by which you need to move the spheres, you'll need to give us more information because there are infinitely many ways you could move the spheres so they touch only at a point.  You probably want to get a unit vector on the line between the centers, then scale that vector by the above distance.

Comment: Good Question. Assume that both sphere centres intersected are on **X-Axis**. Now, the the centre movement of either a of sphere to exactly to touch to the another will be only along **X-Axis** and not along all the 3 Axis.

Comment: @templatetypedef : Unfortunately that's all the information i have .The two centers and their respective radii . What i'm trying to address here is the case of a large time step simulation and two spheres intersecting . In such a case getting to know how far out in a particular direction i will have to push the sphere out so that it is only a collision handling problem from there on which is already handled.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the two spheres overlap, then you could compute the distance between their centers.  You could then add together the two spheres' radii to get the minimum distances that the spheres must be from one another such that they touch only at a point.  The difference between the two (sum of the radii minus the distance between the centers) should be the amount the spheres need to move apart from one another so that they touch only at a point.

Comment: @templatetypedef- It's a mere coincidence that out answers are identical :)

Comment: @Mahesh- Isn't math awesome?  Two people who have never met can work on the same problem and come to the same answer within seconds of each other. :-)

Comment: Yes, Maths is awesome. But your answers are always very good and descriptive. I see your answers on C++ questions and learn new things from it. I am just a beginner. Hope to give answers as good as yours one day :)